# Fibonacci in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, complexity-theory, fibonacci

So here's a fibonacci term-calculating function (in Ruby):

```
def fibfast(n)
  xs = [0,1]
  (n-1).times do |i|
    next_term = xs.sum
    xs[0]=xs[1]
    xs[1]=next_term
   end
   return xs[1]
 end
```

I am pretty sure it has constant space complexity (its only stored data is in xs), and linear time complexity (it uses one loop to calculate the nth term of the sequence).

My question is, is the function recursive? It uses values that it calculates to do more calculations, but never calls itself. My other question is, how do I get this same time-space compactness in Haskell? Haskell functions I have found either have space complexity greater than O(1), returning an entire list of terms, and/or they have time complexity greater than O(n) because they use the typical recursive definition.

Any thoughts appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why would a recursive defintion have a higher time complexity.

Comment: The recursively defined Fibonacci function requires more calculations, I believe it has complexity of O(2^n).

Comment: @ZacharyBechnoefer: not if you use *accumulators*.

Comment: So like this stuff?
http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/04/14/recursion-best-practices/#tail-recursion

Comment: yes, using accumulators is usually good for tail recursion optimization, but it can also - if carefully chosen - reduce the time complexity.

Comment: Relevant: https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence

Comment: If you simultaneously switch from iterative to recursive *and* from this standard algorithm to the naive algorithm, then yes, you get O(fib(n)) time complexity. But *just* switching from iterative to recursive style -- while keeping the same algorithm -- will keep the same O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, is the function recursive? It uses values that it calculates to do more calculations, but never calls itself.

**No**: recursion means that something is defined in terms of itself. The `fibfast` function is not defined in terms of itself.

> My other question is, how do I get this same time-space compactness in Haskell? Haskell functions I have found either have space complexity greater than O(1), returning an entire list of terms, and/or they have time complexity greater than O(n) because they use the typical recursive definition.

You can use the following function:

```
fibfast :: Int -> Int
fibfast n = fib' 0 1 n
    where fib' a b n | n <= 1 = b
                     | otherwise = fib' b (a+b) (n-1)
```

So here we define a recursive function `fib'` and use two accumulators `a` and `b` that store the last two values in the sequence. Each iteration, the two are updated and we decrement the number of iterations we have to do until it hits a number `n` less than or equal to `1` in which case we return the second accumulator.

A problem can be that Haskell usually does not evaluate expressions eagerly, but *lazily*. So it stores `a+b` instead of calculating `a+b`. As a result the expression tree rapidly will be like `a+b+a+b+a+b...`, which thus grows rapidly. We can for instance use *bang patterns*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

fibfast :: Int -> Int
fibfast n = fib' 0 1 n
    where fib' a !b !n | n <= 1 = b
                       | otherwise = fib' b (a+b) (n-1)
```

Comment: Very cool! Was there a particular class you studied this in? Like, Algorithm Design or something? Thanks!

Comment: @ZacharyBechhoefer: Nope. Actually I first learned about accumulators in a logic programming course (Prolog). But logic and functional programming have some common background.

Comment: @ZacharyBechhoefer this is (among other places, I'm sure) taught in Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP), very early in th book – it actually uses fibonacci as the example program too, comparing iterative vs recursive *procedures* vs *processes*